# Передача содержимого файла по сети

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Не могу понять, почему не записывается файл на стороне сервера при приеме бинарной информации от клиента? В чем может быть проблема?

```
# SERVER 
import socketserver as ss

HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 50007
class superTCPUnlimitedServer(ss.BaseRequestHandler):

    def setup(self):
        pass

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        print("Server connected by ", self.client_address[0])

        with open('input.tst', 'ab') as f:
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()  
            while self.data:
                print("Начало приема файла")
                f.write(self.data)
                self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip() 
        print("Файл закрыт")    
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print("Файл получен")
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(bytes("файл получен", "utf-8"))

    def finish(self):
        pass    

with ss.ThreadingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), superTCPUnlimitedServer) as server:
    server.serve_forever() # server.shutdown() останавливает цикл serve_forever()
```

```
# CLIENT
import socket
import threading


HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 50007
data = "Hello super server"
    
# Create a socket (SOCK_STREAM means a TCP socket)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    # Connect to server and send data
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    with open("001055.test", "rb") as file:
        sock.send(file.read())  
    
    # Receive data from the server and shut down
    received = str(sock.recv(1024), "utf-8")
    print("Sent:     {}".format(data))
    print("Received: {}".format(received))
```

Comment: А что у вас в файле "001055.test"? Может он пустой? )

Comment: В том то и дело что не пустой. Размер файла 1271 байт. В нем бинарная информация

Comment: Тогда вопрос - зачем вы делаете `.strip()`, если там бинарная информация?

Comment: Использование .strip() взял из примера socketserver.TCPServer в документации к модулю socketserver. Ссылка https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socketserver.html

Comment: Ну там видимо текстовый файл обрабатывается. Как `strip()` на байты подействует мне сложно сказать. Может и никак, а может обрежет что-то лишнее.

Comment: метод strip() вообще убрал из кода. Все остается по прежнему: бинарные данные приходят на сервер, я их вижу. Цикл while  работает, так как объем принятых данных больше чем 1024 дважды выходит в консоль запись    "Начало приема файла". На этом все. Блок кода начинающийся на print("Файл закрыт") не работает. Ошибок пр  этом никаких нет.

Comment: Когда  self.data = self.request.recv(1024) получает нуль данных сервер виснет.

Comment: Мне сейчас некогда заниматься, попробуйте больше отладочной печати добавить и т.д., посмотреть что в переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Ключевая строка:

```
self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
```

В данном случае, при очередной итерации цикла while, когда все байты уже приняты, self.request.recv(1024) бесконечно ожидает новую порцию данных. Было принято решение добавить атрибут CHUNK класса SuperTCPUnlimitedServer и в цикле while сравнивать длину CHUNK с размером принятых данных. Если очередная порция данных меньше атрибута CHUNK, это говорит о том что поступила последняя порция данных. Решение не оптимальное. Проблемы возникнут если вдруг размер получаемого файла кратен значению CHUNK.

Итоговый код:

```
import socketserver as ss

HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 50007



class SuperTCPUnlimitedServer(ss.BaseRequestHandler):
    CHUNK = 1024
    def setup(self):
        pass

    def handle(self):

        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        print("Server connected by ", self.client_address[0])
        with open('input.ff', 'ab') as f:
            self.data = self.request.recv(self.CHUNK)
            while 1:
                if len(self.data) < self.CHUNK:
                    f.write(self.data)
                    break
                f.write(self.data)
                self.data = self.request.recv(self.CHUNK)
        print("Файл закрыт")
        print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
        print("Файл получен")
        # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
        self.request.sendall(bytes("файл получен", "utf-8"))

    def finish(self):
        pass

with ss.ThreadingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), SuperTCPUnlimitedServer) as server:
    server.serve_forever()
```